# Disabling the editing of Group Titles

Tags: organic-groups

I'm trying to stop the editing of Group Titles (Content Types that are set as Groups) by users. With Drupal (v7.21) I've added Organic Groups (7.x-2.1) and set it so that the Group manager does not have full permissions. Instead I've created a Role for them called 'owner' and give them the ability to edit the group but not administer the group. I want them to be able to change the Group Body but not the Title. I have the Organic groups field access module installed and that lets me stop them editing fields like the Body but it doesn't allow me to stop them editing the Title. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either of these two modules [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) or [Automatic Entity Label](http://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) to hide the title field. Use tokens to give the groups a name and hide the field on the edit form.

Comment: Thanks. After looking at the modules available I think I'll have to code my own. As there doesn't appear to be one that allows admin to restrict the editing of specific node titles but still allow them to be viewed. Unless anyone knows of one.

Comment: You could create a new filed called group_title and use the token in one of the modules above. Then use field permission module to set the permissions for who can edit that field. I know field permission works per content type but not sure if it work per node. There are some modules that deal with per node permission but can't think of one right now.

Answer (score 0):

Display Suite 2.x also comes with field permissions, which I think also works with title fields.
@Dee: This issue is not about "per node", though, it is "per role per content type", if I understand it correctly.